# Does SharePoint Enterprise Search indexes attached documents in InfoPath Form?

Tags: infopath

Does SharePoint Enterprise Search indexes attached documents in InfoPath Form ? I want to search attached document content and name, is it possible ? Well, as per my knowledge, SharePoint Enterprise Search index attached documents in list. Is it possible with InfoPath ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the content of the attachments are not indexed.  Goes the same for List items.  The attachement is attributed to the List item.

Answer (score 1):

I know a few people have verified and confirmed that attachments are indexed and items themselves appear in search results:

http://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/are-list-attachments-indexed-in-sharepoint-search/

I think the storage mechanism for attachments in list items is different than InfoPath form (http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2010/04/top-10-questions-infopath-file-attachments) so the behavior could be different for attachments with InfoPath form though. You may have to try yourself.